# Best way to measure 230VAC

Tags: adc, isolation

I'm trying to design a circuit to measure power of 230VAC (MAINS), with the ADC of a small MCU.

I have designed the part of the circuit to measure current, but my solution to measure voltage is getting a bit messy.

If have come up with a solution using an opto-coupler, but I'm not sure, it is the best way to do it.
I have also looked at transformers, but the seem expensive and kinda big.

Please come with some good suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Vishay IL300](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf) is an **analog optocoupler** with excellent **linearity** (0.01 % servo). It contains 2 identical photodiodes, one of which you use in a feedback loop.

[image]

Obviously \$V_{CC}\$ and \$GND\$ on the left hand side (power of U1 and the optocoupler's pin 3) are different and isolated from \$V_{CC}\$ and \$GND\$ at the right.

> *Note: **Servo linearity** means that neither LED nor photo-diode need to have a linear characteristic (they don't), but that they can achieve this linearity by using them in a feedback system like the one shown in the schematic. The conditions for such linearity are good matching between photo-diodes and a good matching of the current transfer function between LED and either photo-diode.*

Comment: Plus one million for isolation - 230VAC is scary stuff.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed for my design, very good linearity.

Comment: @AngryEE - shocking stuff! :-)

Answer (score -3):

There are 9V AC Poweradapters that you can plug into the mains with a normal plug. Those are safer to use and the output voltage corresponds to the mains voltage. So that if you have that and a current transformer to measure the current, you can then calculate the real power consumption.

-> https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about measuring mains voltage directly using a MCU.

Comment: There is no advantage in measuring mains voltage directly I can see when you are interested in mains power. Also he already mentioned that he looked into transformers and found they were heavy and big. Which is not the case if you look for 9V AC Wall plugs.

Comment: Also, the question is about measuring mains POWER, not only voltage. Look at the Link I gave to see a safe way for doing exactly that.

Comment: Your answer adds very little to what has already been provided a few years ago. Answers relying heavily on links are discouraged. Perhaps reword some of it into your answer if you think it is useful.